# Adding environment variables to Ubuntu srever when .env file is in .gitignore

Tags: node.js, git, ubuntu, pm2, api-key

I have a Github repository with my project that is being hosted on an Ubuntu server. When I include my .env file in my repository and "git pull" onto the Ubunut server, the website loads with no problem. But when I put my .env file in .gitignore, then I "git pull" my project onto the Ubuntu server, the website is down and I get this error in my "pm2 logs":

```
0|app      | OpenAIError: The OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable is missing or empty; either provide it, or instantiate the OpenAI client with an apiKey option, like new OpenAI({ apiKey: 'My API Key' }).
```

My question is: how do I add environment variables to my Ubuntu server, while keeping all my API keys hidden?

Comment: Just add the .env file back... Also depending where you deploy it, you can utilize an automated way of managing those environment variables...

Comment: @SharpDev Thanks for your response! I thought you're not supposed to but your API keys in your github repo for security purposes. Also, when I deploy won't people be able to access my keys?

Comment: NOOO don't put them in your github repo... Just add them to your production environment afterwards (when you deploy it).

Comment: @SharpDev Would you mind giving me a little bit of guidance on how to do that?

Comment: normally I wouldn't, but because you asked. I'll try to help you. Join the chat room here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255992/discussion-with-ek2466

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must avoid pushing your env variables to the github repo. Instead, in your hosting server, take the pull of your repo and create a .env file with your environment variables.

In case you don't have GUI for your hosting server, you can make use of your terminal to create it.

Type the following command in your ssh terminal after connecting to your server:

> nano .env

After that, you can type or copy paste your environment variables along with its value into the terminal and press ***CTRL + X*** and then ***Y*** to save and exit from nano editor.

Done.